# include PKCS11 library in Java

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, pkcs#11

I have PCKS11 dll and so files for my token.and i want to use `[jacknji11][1]` library.

my problem is how can i import the dll OR so files to my project.

i use `System.loadLibrary("parskey11");` to import my library but i get below Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.pkcs11.jacknji11.jna.JNANative.C_InitToken(Lcom/sun/jna/NativeLong;[BLcom/sun/jna/NativeLong;[B)I
at org.pkcs11.jacknji11.jna.JNANative.C_InitToken(Native Method)
at org.pkcs11.jacknji11.jna.JNA.C_InitToken(JNA.java:119)
at org.pkcs11.jacknji11.C.InitToken(C.java:235)
at org.pkcs11.jacknji11.CE.InitToken(CE.java:272)
at com.mmdt.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

i just copy my `libparskey11.so` file to jni folder in project and use below code :

```
    private static final long INITSLOT = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CE.InitToken(INITSLOT, "pincode".getBytes(), "TEST".getBytes());
    long session = CE.OpenSession(INITSLOT, CKS.RW_PUBLIC_SESSION, null,
            null);
    CE.Login(session, CKU.SO, "pincode".getBytes());
    CE.InitPIN(session, "pincode2".getBytes());
    CE.Logout(session);
    CE.Login(session, CKU.USER, "pincode".getBytes());
    byte[] somenewpin = "somenewpin".getBytes();
    CE.SetPIN(session, "pincode2".getBytes(), somenewpin);
    CE.SetPIN(session, somenewpin, "pincode2".getBytes());

}
```

Comment: whether java and the dll are 32 bit or 64 bit

Comment: i have JRE X64 and have a so file and 64bit dll.

Comment: Hi, were you successfully able to integrate with hardware token using this library?